# combine custom action and smarthome action with google assistant

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, google-home, google-smart-home

I created a custom Google action using @assistant/conversation sdk and a smarthome action using actions-on-google sdk. My question is, how can I combine both and link then with same backend server.

Answer (score 1):

While you can have a single backend server which has both smart home and conversational actions, you cannot have a single Action with both integrations. Rather, you would need to create two independent projects: one smart home and one conversational.

You will probably want to define two endpoints, one for each, but both can be hosted in the same backend. If you are using Node.js, you can have all the same underlying logic and use a routing system like Express to export `/actions/conversation` and `/actions/smarthome`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. One more question please! can we customize the voice response in smarthome actions?? I heard that it's possible using something called ifttt, is that true? and thanks again

Comment: No smart home actions cannot have custom responses, but conversational actions can. IFTTT can be used, but that is something each individual must setup and it's not something that can be done as a smart home provider.

Comment: What do you mean by each individual must setup? can you explain more!

Comment: IFTTT can be used by each user to create automations for themselves. [This article](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-use-ifttt-with-google-home-4172627) might explain a bit more